# Node.js Crypto En- / Decrypting Buffer somehow decreases in size

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, cryptography, node-crypto

I'm trying to encrypt a text using AES-256-CBC. For this I'm using the node.js crypto module.
Now I'm having trouble understanding something. I convert my plainText into a buffer and want to pass it to the cipher that way. The buffer size of the plainText is 53 bytes (which is right because it is also 53 characters long). But after the cipher.update() has run, the resulting buffer is only 48 bytes. How can this be?

```
// Generate ivBytes depending on the (byte) size of the used algorithm
const ivBytes = itf.generateRandomBytes(options.ivByteSize);
// create the cipher with the used algorithm, key and the generated ivBytes
const cipher = itf.createCipherIV(options.algorithm, key, ivBytes);

let plainBytes = Buffer.from(plainText, "utf-8");

let cipherBytes = cipher.update(plainBytes);

cipherBytes = cipher.final();

//  combine ivBytes with cipherBytes
//   |----------- ivBytes -----------|----------- cipherBytes -------------|
//   \___________ 16  Byte _________/ \______________x Bytes_______________/
// |                                                                        |
//  \______________________________________________________________________/
//                                        V
//                              encode this combination

let ivAndCipherBytes = null;
// attach ivBytes to back or front of cipherBytes
if (options.ivAtBack) {
  ivAndCipherBytes = Buffer.concat([cipherBytes, ivBytes]);
} else {
  ivAndCipherBytes = Buffer.concat([ivBytes, cipherBytes]);
}
```

Here a screenshot to see the size of the buffers in the debugger:
[image: screenshot to see the inline size of the buffers]

I'd expected it to be 64 Byte long, because:

- block size for AES is 16 Byte
- 53 Byte / 16 Byte = 3,3
  -> 16 Byte * 4 = 64 Byte

The counter part is a C# WPF application which uses the System.Security.Cryptography lib which behaves like expected and returns a 64 Byte array for the above example.

I don't really want to use the cipher.update() function like in the node.js crypto docs because I want to attach the iv as buffer to the encrypted buffer and encode it all together before sending it.

Can anybody help me out here or point me in the right direction?
Big thanks in advance!

Comment: You also get encrypted data from cipher.final() ..

Comment: @EbbeM.Pedersen thanks for the comment. What would that offer me?

Comment: Is it even correct that cipher.update decreases the buffer size?

Comment: Please don't post a screenshot of your code, post the code itself.

Comment: I attached the code from the screenshot. The screenshot was only to show the length of the buffers during debugging

Comment: The data from the `update()` and `final()` call must also be concatenated (s. Ebbe M. Pedersen's comment).

Comment: ahh now I get it. And now its painfully clear! Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

As @Ebbe M. Pedersen and user 9014097 already mentioned in the comments. I needed to concat the result of the update function with the result of the final function like this:

```
// get the plainText Bytes
let plainBytes = Buffer.from(plainText, "utf-8");
// feed them to the cipher (which could be done multiple times
let cipherBytes = cipher.update(plainBytes);
// but at the end attach the result of the final block
cipherBytes = Buffer.concat([cipherBytes, cipher.final()]);
```

This returns an byte array of the expected size of 64. Thank you help! I couldn't see the wood for the trees!